# Activities are always collapsed in rehosted designer

Tags: android-activity, designer, workflow-foundation-4, rehosting

I'm trying to rehost the designer, but every time I slap a workflow into the designer:

```
_workflowDesigner = new WorkflowDesigner();
// added to UI here
Properties.Content = _workflowDesigner.PropertyInspectorView;
_workflowDesigner.Load(myWorkflowInstance);
```

where `myWorkflowInstance` is a workflow defined in a referenced assembly.  I have done the magic `Register` to get the default activity metadata registered:

```
new DesignerMetadata().Register();
```

and I've registered all my custom NativeActivities:

```
public static void Register(IEnumerable<Type> activityTypes)
{            
    // activityTypes are all my custom NativeActivities
    // and all workflows (root of System.Activities.Activity)
    var builder = new AttributeTableBuilder();
    var attrGroups =
        from x in activityTypes
        from y in x.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<Attribute>()
        group y by x into g 
        select g;

    foreach (var typeGroup in attrGroups)
        builder.AddCustomAttributes(typeGroup.Key, typeGroup.ToArray());
    MetadataStore.AddAttributeTable(builder.CreateTable());
}
```

yet, when I load an activity in the designer this is what I get:

[image: Why r u collapsed?]

What am I missing here?

---

I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that these workflows are compiled and only exist within the Implementation property of an Activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your workflow instance wrapped in an ActivityBuilder?

Update:
Investigating a little further here I found one possible solution using the WorkflowInspectionServices.

```
var activities = WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities(new DemoWorkflow());
designer.Load(activities.First());
```

Comment: Nope, I tried doing that, however, and still got the same result.  What's the AB for?

Comment: The ActivityBuilder creates the root element in the designer. Normally I use a WD.Load(path to XAML) and that works fine. But then I also use the Designer attribute to link Activity with ActivityDesigner.

Comment: First, the Activity doesn't have a designer; its a compiled workflow.  A workflow doesn't have a Designer attribute, but all the activities you drag into it do have them.  I am loading and inspecting activities within an assembly, so I do not have the option of getting the original xaml.  All I have are the workflow types and instances of those types.

Comment: Thanks much for spending some time on this!  This is the first time I've heard of that type, so I much appreciate your help on this.  It does behave a little bit strangely, however.  When I was testing it, I got a NRE in a call to CacheMetadata in one of my activities.  But calling it again wouldn't result in an exception being thrown.  I think the Workflow designer and runtime are a bit more careful with badly or hastily written activities.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of reflector and reflection has led me to this travesty:

```
var impl = (typeof(DemoWorkflow)
            .GetProperty("Implementation", 
                         BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(new DemoWorkflow(), new object[0]) 
            as System.Func<System.Activities.Activity>)();

_workflowDesigner.Load(new ActivityBuilder { Implementation = impl });
```

Is this it?  Seriously?  I feel sick knowing that I wrote that.  Dirty.

I noticed in reflector that the xaml for the workflow actually is embedded in the assembly in a resource stream:
[image: the stream in Reflector]

but all attempts to use this failed.

```
var target = typeof(DemoWorkflow);
var name = string.Format("{0}.obj.Debug.{1}.g.xaml", 
                         target.Assembly.GetName().Name, 
                         target.Name);
Activity derp = null;
using (var stream = assy.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
{
    var reader = new XamlXmlReader(stream, new XamlSchemaContext());
    // throws an exception as the property Implementation is in the xaml;
    // it is protected and cannot be set, so deserialization blows up
    derp = ActivityXamlServices.Load(reader);
}
```

I don't see any other option at this point.

Comment: The XAMl in the resources is actually slightly different that the XAML in the original file. The root element is no longer Activity but your DemoWorkflow. I have found another solution using the WorkflowInspectionServices, see my other message.

Comment: @maurice actually, the xaml in the resources is the serialized root workflow activity; its just that conceptually that root doesn't exist in your mental model of what you've designed.  I've since seen you can configure deserialization to not throw when encountering protected/internal serialized properties.